# EditText lose focus only when I leave the screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I am trying to close the keyboard when the focus of `EditText` has been lost. And I use this code for that

```
edt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (!hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Log.d(TAG, "edt focus lost");
            }

            if (hasFocus)
                Log.d(TAG, "edt has focus");
        }
    });
```

When I touch it, I immediately get the focus. But I don't lose focus until I leave the screen.

I tried opening other `Dialogs` on the page, touching other `Views` with their own listeners, but "focus lost" message is not fired before I leave the screen.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A focusable view (such as this `EditText`) only loses focus when another **focusable** view gains it. Most views are not focusable by default.